# Add a "lookup" column in a Kendo Grid

Tags: templates, grid, kendo-ui

I have a Kendo Grid which represents a many-to-many join table (between Parts and Templates).  I want to look up the `PartID` with a combo box that lists parts by `PartNumber` instead of by `PartID`.

A rough image of what I  want to acheive.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The question is not clarified. Basically how to deal with foreign key columns is covered in this [demo](http://demos.kendoui.com/web/grid/foreignkeycolumn.html). Also this one is [pretty](http://demos.kendoui.com/web/grid/editing-custom.html) similar.

Comment: The editing custom does exactly what I need, thanks!  FYI, there seems to be an error in the ASP.NET MVC version of the demo, it does not include the `EditorTemplateName` on category column.